# Error Viewing Participants from Event Screen

Tags: civievent

I have a drupal 7 site running Civi 4.6.5 and using it for event registrations.

When attempting to view Participants from the Event page, I receive a `DB Error: syntax error`.   See backtrace below.  I am able to view a report of registered participants without an issue - just problems using the icon on the event page.  Any ideas?

```
#0 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(182): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(931): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#4 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(564): DB_Error->DB_Error(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#5 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(899): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
#7 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#9 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2442): DB_common->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#10 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1634): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#11 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(325): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#12 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1221): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...", TRUE)
#13 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(4609): CRM_Core_DAO::singleValueQuery("SELECT count( DISTINCT  civicrm_participant.id )  FROM civicrm_contact contac...")
#14 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Selector/Search.php(288): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->searchQuery(0, 0, NULL, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, NULL)
#15 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(233): CRM_Event_Selector_Search->getTotalCount(4, NULL)
#16 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Search.php(336): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->__construct(Object(CRM_Event_Selector_Search), NULL, NULL, 4, Object(CRM_Event_Form_Search), 1, NULL)
#17 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Search.php(124): CRM_Event_Form_Search->postProcess()
#18 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(455): CRM_Event_Form_Search->preProcess()
#19 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(94): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#20 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Search), "display")
#21 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_Search), "display")
#22 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(353): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#23 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#24 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#25 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#26 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(489): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#27 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "search")
#28 /includes/menu.inc(517): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#29 /index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#30 {main}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is been resolved in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16858 against coming 4.6.6. You can find the fix here https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6238.

Comment: Thank you!  I searched and could not find this fix, appreciate you providing the link for the fix.  All good!